# How to properly define a middleware class in Django v1.11?

Tags: python, django, django-middleware

I'm working on Django (v1.11) project and need to **provide some middleware functionality** to the site. This version of Django modify old `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting as described in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/):

> A new style of middleware was introduced for use with the new
>   `MIDDLEWARE` setting.

However, **I can't understand how NEW middleware works**. After reading the middleware's documentation I come to the following conclusion:

```python
class FooMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        return self.get_response(request)

    def process_template_response(self, request, response):
        # do something here
        return response
```

I thought that it'll work, but unfortunately **code above doesn't work** and is completely ignored by Django (**without any error!**).

---

When I do something like the following:

```python
class FooMiddleware(object):    
    def process_template_response(self, request, response):
        # do something here
        return response
```

...an error occured (because `__init__` method of `object` class has no arguments):

> TypeError: object() takes no parameters

---

When I change the code as follows **everything works**:

```python
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class FooMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        # do something here
        return response
```

**But!** The `MiddlewareMixin` is related to the `deprecation` utils and used for compatibility purposes:

> Django provides `django.utils.deprecation.MiddlewareMixin` to ease
>   creating middleware classes that are compatible with both `MIDDLEWARE`
>   and the old `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.

---

**Question:** How to properly define a middleware class in Django v1.11?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining [`process_template_response`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/#process-template-response) is only useful if your response instance has a `render()` method. If not, you should move your custom code into the `__call__` method.

```
class FooMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        # Do something here
        return response
```

Comment: [Alasdair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113962/alasdair), thanks. I thought that the `process_template_response` method is replacement for the old `process_response` method.